# Space opera books about a human ship captain, androids, aliens artefacts and a plot to destroy the Earth

Tags: story-identification, books

This was a series of books (space opera) about a man who becomes a spaceship captain, because he is needed to conduct business on other planets (androids cannot be captains).

An evil, always plotting, android tries to use our hero. The android is cast away and in revenge uses Earth's total destruction as a threat.

There are some alien artefacts shaped like metal discs.

Earth doesn't know about life in space. Main character is only one taken to space. He took some nanobots... so he is a bit stronger....

Comment: When would this have been published? In what language did you read it in, was it a translation? Any recollection of the covers?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: It was in English.

Comment: When? Does it realy matter? In last 4 years I've read around 1000 different books .....writen from 1800 until now.

Comment: @UNKNOWNUNKNOWN - It greatly helps to know when you read it and when you think it was published. If it's relatively new (post-internet age), looking for it will be vastly different than looking for something that's old.

Comment: It was e-book and I read it 6-7 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [*Omega Force*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/17413290-omega-rising) series of books by Joshua Dalzelle.

> Jason Burke was a man hiding from himself in a small cabin high in the
> American Rocky Mountains when his simple, quiet life was shattered one
> night by what he first assumed was an aviation mishap. But when he
> investigates the crash, what he finds will yank him out of his
> self-imposed exile and thrust him into a world he could have never
> imagined.
>
> He suddenly finds himself trapped on a damaged alien spacecraft and
> plunged into a universe of interstellar crime lords and government
> conspiracies, along the way meeting strange new friends… and enemies.
> As he struggles to find his way back home he is inexorably drawn
> deeper into a world where one misstep could mean his death. Or worse.
> He desperately wants to get back to Earth, but it may be the end for
> him.
>
> … or is it just the beginning?

Comment: You should add some details about the book, a link, when it was published, etc.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say: you should also mark this answer as accepted.